refreshApex not rerunning wire handler after entering error state
I'm seeing that once a LWC's wire handler receives an error, refreshApex stops retriggering the wire handler. Is this expected behavior or is there something I am doing wrong?
My understanding of the relationship between wire handlers and refreshApex is that whenever the data retrieved by the Apex function has become stale, I should call refreshApex to rerun the apex function. It will retrieve the new data, and if the data has changed, then the wire handler will be rerun with the new data.
This is working when the Apex function returns a success state, as long as it doesn't return an error, whenever I call refreshApex, the wire handler is rerun whenever the data has changed.
But if the Apex function returns an error, then re-calling it using refreshApex doesn't rerun the wire handler, even if the error has changed, or if it begins returning successfully (I am able to verify it is calling the Apex function and returning a non error by looking at the network calls using the browser's developer tools - so it is calling the Apex function fine it just isn't calling the wire handler with the updated data).
LWC:
import {LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/SodaController.foo';
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class Soda extends LightningElement {
    @wire(foo, {})
    gotFoo(response) {
        this.wireObj = response;
        const {data, error} = response;

        if (error !== undefined) {
            console.info('error', error);
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }

        if (data !== undefined) {
            console.info('data', data);
            this.data = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        }
    }
    wireObj = undefined;
    data = undefined;
    error = undefined;

    reload() {
        refreshApex(this.wireObj);
    }
}
---
<template>
    <lightning-button-icon
        icon-name="utility:refresh"
        alternative-text="Retry"
        class="slds-m-left_xx-small"
        title="Retry"
        variant="border-filled"
        onclick={reload}
    ></lightning-button-icon>
</template>

Apex:
public with sharing class SodaController {
      @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
      public static String foo() {
        String x = 'wow';
        if (true)
             throw new SodaException('No data');
        return x;
    }
    public class SodaException extends Exception {}
}

So with that code you can run it and get the 'No data' error object from console.info('error', error). Then if you update the foo function to not return an error, and to just return the string x, and press the refresh button on the LWC, it'll rerun the Apex function and get the string.  But it won't rerun gotFoo with the new value, since we don't see it run console.info('data', data).
I'm wondering if this is expected behavior or if anyone else has come across this bug and found a solution?
Also, here is a related issue the LWC Github page, which is where I started before being told to ask here. https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/3990

Update:
I spoke with Salesforce Support about this and this is more-or-less a bug with how LDS handles caching.  They said they would work to add better documentation on the current behavior and would fix it in a future release (though they gave no timeline on that).
Until then, as a workaround you can add a additional parameter to the Apex function, and rather than using refreshApex to trigger re-calling the Apex function, you can increment that parameter to force it to retrigger.
LWC:
import {LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/SodaController.foo';

export default class Soda extends LightningElement {
    @wire(foo, {triggerParam: "$wireTrigger"})
    gotFoo(response) {
        this.wireObj = response;
        const {data, error} = response;

        if (error !== undefined) {
            console.info('error', error);
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }

        if (data !== undefined) {
            console.info('data', data);
            this.data = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        }
    }
    wireObj = undefined;
    data = undefined;
    error = undefined;
    wireTrigger = 0;

    reload()
        this.wireTrigger = this.wireTrigger + 1;
    }
}
---
<template>
    <lightning-button-icon
        icon-name="utility:refresh"
        alternative-text="Retry"
        class="slds-m-left_xx-small"
        title="Retry"
        variant="border-filled"
        onclick={reload}
    ></lightning-button-icon>
</template>

Apex:
public with sharing class SodaController {
      @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
      public static String foo(Integer triggerParam) {
        String x = 'wow';
        if (true)
             throw new SodaException('No data');
        return x;
    }
    public class SodaException extends Exception {}
}


Did you sole this at all? I am seeing the same issue .

@Melissa I spoke with Salesforce Support and they basically said it was a bug with how LDS handles caching. Basically it doesn't cache 500-error responses which leads to this undocumented buggy behavior.
They technically didn't acknowledge it as a bug, since there isn't any documentation on how it is meant to work, but they did say they'd open an internal ticket and work to fix it in a future release.
I've updated my question above to also include the suggested workaround for the time being.

I spoke with Salesforce Support about this and this is more-or-less a bug with how LDS handles caching. They said they would work to add better documentation on the current behavior and would fix it in a future release (though they gave no timeline on that).
Until then, as a workaround you can add a additional parameter to the Apex function, and rather than using refreshApex to trigger re-calling the Apex function, you can increment that parameter to force it to retrigger.
LWC:
import {LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/SodaController.foo';

export default class Soda extends LightningElement {
    @wire(foo, {triggerParam: "$wireTrigger"})
    gotFoo(response) {
        this.wireObj = response;
        const {data, error} = response;

        if (error !== undefined) {
            console.info('error', error);
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }

        if (data !== undefined) {
            console.info('data', data);
            this.data = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        }
    }
    wireObj = undefined;
    data = undefined;
    error = undefined;
    wireTrigger = 0;

    reload()
        this.wireTrigger = this.wireTrigger + 1;
    }
}
---
<template>
    <lightning-button-icon
        icon-name="utility:refresh"
        alternative-text="Retry"
        class="slds-m-left_xx-small"
        title="Retry"
        variant="border-filled"
        onclick={reload}
    ></lightning-button-icon>
</template>

Apex:
public with sharing class SodaController {
      @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
      public static String foo(Integer triggerParam) {
        String x = 'wow';
        if (true)
             throw new SodaException('No data');
        return x;
    }
    public class SodaException extends Exception {}
}

